# Spring Boot form with many inputs + upload

Tags: spring, forms, spring-boot

I have a form in my Ecommerce app in Spring Boot. It works well. 
My controller part looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/add",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String adminAddProductSubmit(@ModelAttribute(value = "product") Product product){
    productServiceJpa.addProduct(product);
    return "/admin/added";
}
```

Now I want to add upload input to the uploading image. There is a problem.
I tried this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/add",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String adminAddProductSubmit(final @ModelAttribute(value = "product") Product product, final @RequestAttribute(value = "image") MultipartFile uploadingFile){
    File file = new File(uploadingdir + uploadingFile.getOriginalFilename());

    try {
        uploadingFile.transferTo(file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    productServiceJpa.addProduct(product);
}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

My form:

```
<form th:action="@{/admin/add}" th:object="${product}"  class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h2>Nazwa przedmiotu</h2>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Tytuł</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" th:field="*{title}"  class="form-control" />

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="category" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Kategoria</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" th:field="*{category}"  class="form-control" />

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="amount" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Ilość</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" th:field="*{amount}" class="form-control" />

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="shortDesc" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Krótki opis</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" th:field="*{shortDesc}" class="form-control" />

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="description" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Opis</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" th:field="*{description}" class="form-control" />

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="price" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Cena</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" th:field="*{price}" class="form-control" />

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="image" class="col-sm-3 control-label">
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="file" th:field="*{image}" class="custom-file-input"/>

                <span class="custom-file-control"></span>
            </div>
        </label>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Dodaj"/>
</form>
```

Can you tell me how can I send my object and get it in @ModelAttribute and get file from file input?

There are many tutorials, f.e in Spring Boot documentation, but there are only upload forms. I want to have a form with many text inputs and file input.

Comment: `@RequestAttribute` != `@RequestParam`... Use the proper annotations.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the `@Valid` annotation for your `Product` param, and the next param must be a `BindingResult`. So your method would be:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/add",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String adminAddProductSubmit(final @ModelAttribute(value = "product") @Valid Product product, BindingResult bindingResult, final @RequestParam(value = "image") MultipartFile uploadingFile){
    File file = new File(uploadingdir + uploadingFile.getOriginalFilename());

    try {
        uploadingFile.transferTo(file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    productServiceJpa.addProduct(product);
}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28887780/why-does-bindingresult-have-to-follow-valid) is an explanation of why the `BindingResult` has to come after the `@Valid` annotation.

Comment: @Michalf94 Please read: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)