# Spring MVC Thymeleaf error template overriding inline form error messages

Tags: spring, forms, validation, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm working on validating a form and showing inline errors for fields that don't pass validation using Thymeleaf. I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.8.

I have a `User` object that will be bound to the form. It has fields like: `username` and `email`. Here's the form declaration,

```
<form role="form" class="form" method="post"
    th:action="@{'/admin/user/new'}" th:object="${user}">
```

I set up an error controller like this because I wanted a catch all error page. I also created a template at `src/main/resources/templates/error.html`. This was because the security context was lost on the error page according to this github [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1048), although it indicates the issue should be fixed in my version. Without this controller the default error template is shown, but I have no access to the security context. With this controller in place and the `error.html` template any random error will be handled.

```
@Controller
public class ErrorController extends BasicErrorController {

    /**
     * This Bean declaration provides the Spring Security Context to 4xx responses. This is reported as
     * fixed in Spring Boot 2.0.0:
     *
     * https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1048
     *
     * @param springSecurityFilterChain
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean getSpringSecurityFilterChainBindedToError(
                    @Qualifier("springSecurityFilterChain") Filter springSecurityFilterChain) {

            FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
            registration.setFilter(springSecurityFilterChain);
            registration.setDispatcherTypes(EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class));
            return registration;
    }

    @Autowired
    public ErrorController(ErrorAttributes errorAttributes) {
        super(errorAttributes, new ErrorProperties());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/error")
    public String error(Model model) {
        return "/error";
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return "/__dummyErrorPath";
    }

}
```

For this example I'm just trying to validate the `email` field and to show a message if validation fails next to this field. The class field looks like this on `User`,

```
@NotNull
@Email
private String email;
```

The Thymeleaf field looks like this,

```
<div th:fragment="email" class="form-group">
    <label>Email*</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" th:field="*{email}" th:required="required" />
    <span class="error" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('email')}" th:errors="*{email}">...</span>
</div>
```

The new user form controller method looks like this,

```
@GetMapping("admin/user/new")
public String newUser(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
    model.addAttribute("user", new User());
    return "admin/user/new";
}
```

And the corresponding POST method looks like this,

```
@PostMapping("admin/user/new")
public String newUser(@Valid @ModelAttribute User user, final ModelMap model, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    Assert.notNull(user, "User must not be null");
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "admin/user/new";
    }
    userService.save(user);
    model.clear();
    return "redirect:/admin/user/list";
}
```

In this POST method I'm checking to see if the `BindingResult` has errors. If it does I'm expecting the `admin/user/new` template to be rendered with the inline error message shown. However my catch all error template is being rendered. The URL still shows `/admin/user/new` and refreshing the page still shows the error template.

My main question is how can I use the catch all error page and still show inline errors when I need to if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the `BindingResult` needs to directly follow the `Valid` annotation'd parameter in the parameter list.

See [Why does BindingResult have to follow @Valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28887780/why-does-bindingresult-have-to-follow-valid)

I'd give that a go

Comment: Thank you @benashby that was exactly the issue. I changed the signature to `public String newUser(@Valid @ModelAttribute User user, BindingResult bindingResult, final ModelMap model) {`

Answer (score 0):

What about using this  in html-view?

```
<div th:if="${param.error}"
     th:text="${session['SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION'].message}">
</div>
```