# How to validate a form with binding result?

Tags: spring, forms, validation, thymeleaf

I have a simple form to save an User and I can't get it to show the error messages

I have the exact same structure for saving "Customer" and it works, but when I try to replicate it to User It doesn't work

My log error:

> 2019-08-21 17:07:14.521  WARN 11332 --- [nio-8080-exec-8]
>   .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused
>   by handler execution: org.springframework.validation.BindException:
>   org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
>   Field error in object 'user' on field 'password': rejected value
>   [123]; codes
>   [Size.user.password,Size.password,Size.java.lang.String,Size];
>   arguments
>   [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable:
>   codes [user.password,password]; arguments []; default message
>   [password],2147483647,6]; default message [A senha deve conter pelo
>   menos 6 caracteres.]

User controllers:

```
@GetMapping("/{customerId}/createUser")
public ModelAndView userForm(@PathVariable(value = "customerId", required 
= false) Long customerId,
        @RequestParam(value = "userId", required = false) Long userId, 
Model model) {

    Authentication authentication = 
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

    Optional<Users> authenticatedUserOptional = 
userRepository.findByEmail(authentication.getName());
    model.addAttribute("userLogedIsAdmin", 
authenticatedUserOptional.get().getIsAdmin());

    if (authentication == null || !authentication.isAuthenticated()) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("accessDenied");
        return mv;
    }

    if (!authenticatedUserOptional.isPresent()) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("accessDenied");
        return mv;
    }

    if (customerId != null) {

        Optional<Customers> customerOptional = 
customerRepository.findById(customerId);
        Customers customer = customerOptional.get();

        model.addAttribute("customer", customer);

        if (userId != null) {
            Users existingUser = userRepository.findById(userId).get();
            if (existingUser.getEnabled()) {
                existingUser.setUserStatus(UserStatus.ATIVO);
            } else {
                existingUser.setUserStatus(UserStatus.INATIVO);
            }
            model.addAttribute("user", existingUser);
        } else {
            model.addAttribute("user", new Users());
        }

        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("customerNewUser");
        return mv;
    } else {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("accessDenied");
        return mv;
    }
}

@PostMapping("/{customerId}/createUser")
public ModelAndView saveUser(@PathVariable(value = "customerId", required 
= true) Long customerId,
        @ModelAttribute(name = "user") @Valid Users user, 
RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,
        BindingResult bindingResult) {

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return userForm(customerId, user.getId(), new Model() {

            @Override
            public Model mergeAttributes(Map<String, ?> attributes) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean containsAttribute(String attributeName) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public Map<String, Object> asMap() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public Model addAttribute(String attributeName, Object 
attributeValue) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public Model addAttribute(Object attributeValue) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public Model addAllAttributes(Map<String, ?> attributes) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public Model addAllAttributes(Collection<?> attributeValues) 
{
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }
        });
    }

    // Encrypt password
    if (user.getPassword().equals(user.getMatchPassword())) {
        user.setPassword(encoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        user.setCustomerId(customerId);
        user.setEventDescription("User Admin creation");

        Users returnedUser = userService.save(user);

        List<Authorities> authorities = new ArrayList<Authorities>();
        Authorities auth = new Authorities(new 
AuthoritiesPK(returnedUser.getId(), "ROLE_CLI_ADM"), returnedUser,
                "ROLE_CLI_ADM");
        authorities.add(auth);
        returnedUser.setAuthorities(authorities);
        returnedUser.setEventDescription("Add Admin role");

        for (int i = 0; i < returnedUser.getAuthorities().size(); i++) {
            authorityService.save(returnedUser.getAuthorities().get(i));
        }
        userService.save(returnedUser);
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("redirect:/customers/" + 
customerId);
        return mv;
    } else {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("accessDenied");
        return mv;
    }
}
```

form html:

```
<div class="card mb-3">

                <div class="card-header"
                    th:text="${user?.id} ? #{editUser} : #{newUser}">
                    <i class="fas fa-table"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <form
                        th:action="@{${user?.id} ? '/customers/' + ${customer.id} + '/createUser/' + ${user.id} : '/customers/' + ${customer.id} + '/createUser/'}"
                        th:object="${user}" action="#" method="post">

                        <div class="alert alert-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasAnyErrors()}">
                            <div th:each="detailedError : ${#fields.detailedErrors()}">
                                <span th:text="${detailedError.message}"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                    <label class="text-right label-control"
                                        th:text="#{firstname} + ':'">Firstname:</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname"
                                        th:value="${user?.firstname} ? ${user?.firstname} : ''"
                                        class="form-control" th:placeholder="#{firstname}"
                                        required="required" autofocus="autofocus"
                                        th:field="*{firstname}" /> 
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                    <label class="text-right label-control"
                                        th:text="#{surname} + ':'">Surname:</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <input type="text" id="surname" name="surname"
                                        th:value="${user?.surname} ? ${user?.surname} : ''"
                                        class="form-control" th:placeholder="#{surname}"
                                        autofocus="autofocus" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                    <label class="text-right label-control"
                                        th:text="#{email} + ':'">Email:</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <input th:placeholder="#{email}" required="required"
                                        autofocus="autofocus" id="email" class="form-control"
                                        type="text" th:value="${user?.email} ? ${user?.email} : ''"
                                        name="email" th:field="*{email}" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group" th:if="!${user?.id}">
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                    <label class="text-right label-control"
                                        th:text="#{password} + ':'">Password:</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <input type="password" id="password" name="password"
                                        class="form-control" th:placeholder="#{password}"
                                        required="required" autofocus="autofocus"
                                        th:field="*{password}" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group" th:if="!${user?.id}">
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                    <label class="text-right label-control"
                                        th:text="#{passwordConfirmation} + ':'">Password
                                        confirmation:</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <input type="password" id="matchPassword" name="matchPassword"
                                        class="form-control" th:placeholder="#{password}"
                                        required="required" autofocus="autofocus"
                                        th:field="*{matchPassword}" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group" th:if="${user?.id}">
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                    <label class="text-right label-control"
                                        th:text="#{userStatus} + ':'">Status:</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <select class="form-control form-control" id="userStatus"
                                        name="userStatus">
                                        <option
                                            th:each="userStatus : ${T(br.com.macrosul.stetho.entity.UserStatus).values()}"
                                            th:text="${userStatus}" th:value="${userStatus}"
                                            th:selected="${user.userStatus} eq ${userStatus}"></option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group" id="saveDiv">
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="col-md-5"></div>
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <a class="btn-nounderline" href="#"> <input type="submit"
                                        class="btn btn-md btn-block" value="Save"
                                        th:value="${user?.id} ? #{updateUser} : #{save}" id="save" />
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
```

part of my model:

```
@Entity
public class Users extends BaseEntity {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -1667698094711992210L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = 
"users_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "users_seq", sequenceName = "users_seq", 
allocationSize = 50, initialValue = 1)
@JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_ONLY)
private Long id;
@NotBlank(message = "E-mail não pode estar em branco.")
@NotNull(message = "E-mail deve ser informado.")
@Email(message = "Formato inválido de E-mail.")
@Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
private String email;
@JsonProperty(access = Access.WRITE_ONLY)
@Size(min=6, message="A senha deve conter pelo menos 6 caracteres.")
@NotNull(message = "A senha deve ser informada.")
@NotBlank(message = "A senha não pode estar em branco.")
@NotEmpty(message = "A senha não pode estar vazia.")
@Column(nullable = false)
private String password;
@JsonIgnore
@Transient
private String matchPassword;
@JsonIgnore
@Column(nullable = false)
private Boolean enabled = true;
@NotNull(message = "O nome deve ser informada.")
@NotBlank(message = "O nome não pode estar em branco.")
@NotEmpty(message = "O nome não pode estar vazia.")
@Column(nullable = false)
private String firstname;
private String surname;
@Column(nullable = true)
private Long customerId;
@JsonIgnore
@Transient
private Boolean isAdmin;
@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "user")
private List<Authorities> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Transient
private UserStatus userStatus;
}
```

I simply can't understand why it does not show the error message, I'm pretty sure what's logged is not en error itself... Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Might not be what is failing, but bindingresult has to follow the parameter it is validating. You can see more details on the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28887780/why-does-bindingresult-have-to-follow-valid)

So change:

```
public ModelAndView saveUser(@PathVariable(value = "customerId", required = true) Long customerId,
        @ModelAttribute(name = "user") @Valid Users user, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,
        BindingResult bindingResult) { ... }
```

To:

```
public ModelAndView saveUser(@PathVariable(value = "customerId", required = true) Long customerId,
        RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, @ModelAttribute(name = "user") @Valid Users user,
        BindingResult bindingResult) { ... }
```