# Should the controller call a single function from service layer or call multiple service functions based on required sequence?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, web-services, architecture

Here is a typical Login web service I wrote. I am using the layered architecture (Controller , Service , Model).

Controller :

```
@PostMapping("/login")
public ResponseEntity<Map<String , Object>>login(@RequestBody LoginRequest loginReq){
    String validationFailedMsg = service.validateLogin(loginReq.getEmail() , loginReq.getPassword());
    if(validationFailedMsg != null) {
        BodyBuilder response= ResponseEntity.status(409);
        Map<String , Object> m = new HashMap<>();
        m.put("err", validationFailedMsg);
        return response.body(m);
    }
    AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, String> tokens = service.loginUser(loginReq.getEmail() , loginReq.getPassword());
    if(tokens == null) {
        BodyBuilder response= ResponseEntity.status(409);
        Map<String , Object> m = new HashMap<>();
        m.put("err", "Password is incorrect");
        return response.body(m);
    }
    Map<String , Object> m = new HashMap<>();
    m.put("access_token", tokens.getKey());
    m.put("refresh_token", tokens.getValue());
    return ResponseEntity.ok(m);
}
```

I am first validating the request eg : checking if user exists and all fields are present. After that I am calling the `loginUser` in service layer. If any errors are encountered eg : Password is incorrect, I handle it in the controller.

Here is the register route where I am calling more functions from the service layer. Does this logic come under business logic and should I move it into the service layer?

```
@PostMapping("/register")
public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> register(@RequestBody Person person) {
    String validationFailedMsg = service.validateRegister(person);
    
    if(validationFailedMsg != null) {
        System.out.print(validationFailedMsg);
        BodyBuilder response= ResponseEntity.status(409);
        Map<String , Object> m = new HashMap<>();
        m.put("err", validationFailedMsg);
        return response.body(m);
    }
    person.setPassword(service.hashPassword(person.getPassword()));
    Person newPerson = service.createPerson(person);
    service.emailVerificationSendOTP(newPerson.getEmail());
    Map<String , Object> response = new HashMap<>();
    response.put("msg" , "Enter OTP sent by mail");
    response.put("Person", newPerson);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
}
```

Basically I want to know what really is business logic and it would be great if it could be explained with the help of login and register routes.
Thanks.

Comment: It depends, but why isn't the validation part of the login in the first place? What if you need to do a login from different code? In general your web controller should be nothing more then the integration to the service layer (which should contain the actual logic). The only thing the controller should do is convert the incoming request into something the service can handle and convert the result from the service into something web like.

Comment: ok got it. So it'll be a lot cleaner if I handle all the logic inside the service layer and make the controller just an intermediate layer that accepts the request and passes in the data required by the service layer, takes the response from the service layer and converts it into a http response.
Thankyou!

Comment: You have to take care to not use web related classes in your service layer (as that will tie it to web only). So to pass in parameters you can use a dto or plain Strings etc. Interface wise it feels a bit ugly to return a Map.Entry as a result instead of some DTO containing the information (and throw some exception upon validation errors etc.).

Comment: OK thank you for pointing that out. I'm new to spring and trying to learn best practices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I can help a bit. As said in comments, the idea of the controller is just to be a bridge from the outside world to logic defined in the service, This also add reuse-ability.

If you put too much logic in the Controller, you will end with what it's called a `Fat Controller`

For validation, spring provides validator that you can use in your controller with the `@Valid` annotation, and this will providde you with a `BindingResults` (that's the validation results). Please notice that the **order is very important**, the `BindingResult` **must** be after the `@Valid`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28887839/2597775) you can learn more

And you can throw an exception if validation fails. Rewrite your method as follow:

```java
@PostMapping("/register")
public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> register(@Valid @RequestBody Person person, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        // Validations failed!
        throw new InvalidInputException(bindingResult);
    }

    ...
}
```

To use that validation mechanism you can add some annotation to your `Person`, for example:

```
public class Person{
    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    String username;

    @NotEmpty
    String pass;
}
```

You can learn more about validation [here](https://reflectoring.io/bean-validation-with-spring-boot/)

This could be a basic first filter for some input validadtion, then if you need more checks (like for example, the user must not already exits) that should be done in the service layer. How granular you want your service to be is just up to you and your needs.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and resources. It'll definitely help!